# How to get blade.php.file from function in controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I call ‘check’ function in controller from route ,

```
public function check($id)
{
   return View::make('running');     
}
```

it works , open the running.blade.php file . but when i write –

```
public function font()
{ 
    echo “hello”;

    return View::make(‘running’);
}   

public function check($id)
{
    $this->font();     
}
```

running.blade.php doesnot appear , only a blank page with “hello” show in browser; I think in both cases blade file show in browser.

Comment: `return $this->font()`?

Comment: Thanks it works .

Answer (score 0):

Usually, as mentioned by @Tim Lewis just return the view (and make use of Laravels Request awesomeness, as i guess you're validating your input):

Your example:

```
public function check($id) 
{
    return $this->font();
}
```

The "Laravel way":

```
php artisan make:request FontRequest
```

and then define your validation rules inside the array, eg:

```
// FontRequest.php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'required',
        ...
    ];
```

This makes request validation fun:

```
// YourController.php
public function font(FontRequest $request) { ... }
```

Read more about

- [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)
- [Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers) (also have a look at resource Controllers)

Answer (score 0):

u want to display 'hello' word in running.blade.php

so first modify your controller like this

```
public function check($id){
$dt = "hello";
return view('running' , compact('dt'));
}
```

and add this code your running.blade.php file

```
{{$dt}}
```

then you get "hello" word in running.blade.php